# iOS Crash : libswiftAssetsLibrary.dylib not loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode6

When I tried to run my app on the simulator, everything run fine. But when I try  to run it on a device (iPhone 6, iOS 8.1), it crashes instantly.

It happens only on a macmini, and **not** on my macbook pro. Both are running Yosemite with Xcode 6.1.

Here is the log :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAssetsLibrary.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/03823DE6-B2FD-4A2D-B03F-3770D433CBCA/Lima.app/Lima
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/03823DE6-B2FD-4A2D-B03F-3770D433CBCA/Lima.app/Frameworks/libswiftAssetsLibrary.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x00871000, size=0x00004000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/03823DE6-B2FD-4A2D-B03F-3770D433CBCA/Lima.app/Frameworks/libswiftAssetsLibrary.dylib
  Dyld Version: 353.5
```

#### What I already tried and doesn't work :

- Changing the `Runpath Search Paths` build setting to `@executable_path/Frameworks`
- Go to project build settings and set `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` flag to `YES`
- Regenerating certificate and mobileprovision

Nothing worked.

Thanks !

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Comment: No. Do you have the same ?

Comment: Yes, I have too, At first I thought it was linked to my project. I created a new one, but I have the same problem. It works fine on the simulator, but it crashes on a new Iphone 6 link to a new mac book pro. I am currently updating it to OSX Yosemite (fingers crossed). Which OS do you use right now ?

Comment: It's on Yosemite. it's not a big deal for me because I have the problem on my CI mac. Keep me post if you found the solution, I'll do it for you if I found :)
Hope that'll work on yosemite for you! Do  you have  filevault activated ? It is on my macmini. (Don't think it's related, but I spent so much time on it, I don't know what can it be).

Comment: Ok so it worked. I moved to Yosemite, and I was requested to install new stuffs regarding Xcode. Maybe you should re-install or update Xcode ? Why do use filevault for ?

Comment: I use filevault on the mac, to encrypt all the disk.

Comment: And you, it is related to your problem ? btw, I did not set FileVault while installing Yosemite.

Comment: I don't think it's related, but I tried everything. And I've got FileVault only on this Mac. It's working well on all others Mac.

Comment: You said you tried to create a new project on this mac ? And it doesnt work too ?

Comment: Not yet, but we will investigate soon, thanks :)

Comment: I was using frameworks, the mistake I made was not adding the frameworks into the `Embedded Binaries`.

Answer (score 1):

I just fix the same issue by revoking old certificate and create new one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as mention in the question I already tried this, and it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the exact same error and managed to fix it by regenerating the certificates and mobile provision and adding them to keychain, xcode respectively. I think it might be the case for you as well as the issue only appears on one of your machines.

I'd try going to 'Member Center' and downloading, first the development certificate, clicking on it twice and adding it to the keychain, then mobile provision, clicking on it twice and adding it to Xcode.

You can also try creating the certificates, provision through member center just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This is considered a bug in PromiseKit. Add assets library to your frameworks list to fix.

PromiseKit 2 fixes this (to be released), for PromiseKit 1 there is a fix, but it doesn't always work (depends on how things get linked).